# Distinguish between user generated and my own application generated mouse moves

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, windows-messages, message-loop

My WinForms app moves the mouse cursor about the form simply by setting the `Cursor.Position` property in some kind of a loop with a timer.

I would like this movement to continue only till the user does not wield the mouse himself to move it. As soon as he or she does, I want my code to stop.

Therefore, I need a way to distinguish between mouse moves that the *user generated mouse movement* sent vs. those that my application generates.

Comment: I don't like it very much but...what about a simple flag? bool _mouseMovedByApplication. When MouseMove event handler will be called and _mouseMovedByApplication is false then it has to stop timer.

Comment: @Adriano That needs to be more complex than a single bool, as WM_MOUSEMOVE event are asynchronous (Posted).

Comment: @manuell true, Queue<Point> may works better but I wouldn't start with a (slightly) more complicated solution if simpler one works. Well to be sure he should detach event handler, change location, empty message queue, attach handler again. It may be too much.

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward solution for Windows 8 and up: use the [`GetCurrentInputMessageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448793.aspx) function.

if `originId` is `IMO_INJECTED`, the input is emulated. Otherwise, it usually equals `IMO_HARDWARE`.

Comment: Wouldn't this also detect other applications moving the mouse programatically as being injected, tho'? This may be desired, but I would expect the OP wants to differentiate between moves they generate, and any other moves.

Comment: Yes, this will detect other applications, too, unless they have the `UIAccess` attribute as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448797.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Win32 [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) API to position the mouse cursor, you can set a custom `dwExtraInfo` value in the [MOUSEINPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273.aspx) structure.

When processing an asynchronous (posted) message, you can use the Win32 API [GetMessageExtraInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644937.aspx) to retrieve the custom value.